# Common lisp recursive macro in matrix addition

Tags: recursion, macros, common-lisp

I have to write a recursive macro for list addition in Common Lisp (homework). What I have so far is :

```
(defmacro matrix-add-row (r1 r2 sum_row)
    (if (not (and r1 r2)) `sum_row
        (progn
            `(matrix-add-row (cdr r1) (cdr r2) (cons sum_row (+ (car r1) (car r2))))
            (reverse sum_row)
        )
    )
)
```

I call this function with

```
(matrix-add-row `(1 2) `(3 4) ())
```

and as an output I get unvaluated code instead of numbers (which leads going to infinite loop).

How to put , ` properly (or call the macro properly)?

Comment: Are you trying to define a macro (as you are saying at the beginning of the question), or a function (as you are saying at the end of the question)?

Comment: A macro, thanks for noticing.

Comment: As well as my actual answer, I'd like to point out that your lisp style is a bit odd. Experienced lispers just close parentheses on the last line like in the example code in either my answer or that of @PuercoPop. If you are getting lost with which closing parenthesis matches which opening parenthesis, use a decent text editor that shows matching delimiters. (I use Emacs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, to me this seems a rather bizarre thing to do with a macro. I assume the point is that you use the macro to transform `(matrix-add-row '(1 2) '(3 4))` to an explicit list of sums like `(list (+ 1 3) (+ 2 4))`.

Also, what you have written has several problems which look like you don't quite understand how the backtick works. So I think the easiest way to help is to solve an example for you.

Since this is homework, I'm going to solve a different (but similar) question. You should be able to take the answer and use it for your example. Suppose I want to solve the following:

> Write a macro, `diffs`, which computes all differences of pairs of successive elements in a list. For example,
>
> `(diffs '(1 2 3))` should expand to `(list (- 2 1) (- 3 2))`, which will then evaluate to `(1 1)`.

Note that my macro won't do the actual subtraction, so I can use it even if I don't know some of the numbers until runtime. (The reason I think this sort of question is a bit weird is that it does need to know the length of the list at compile time).

My solution is going to be used as a macro with one argument but if I want to use recursion I'll need to pass in an accumulator too, which I can start with `nil`. So I write something like this:

```
(defmacro diffs (lst &optional accumulator)
  ...)
```

Now what do I do with `lst`? If `lst` is `nil`, I want to bottom out and just return the accumulator, with a call to `list` at the front, which will be code to make my list. Something like this:

```
(defmacro diffs (lst &optional accumulator)
  (cond
    ((null lst)
     ;; You could write `(list ,@accumulator) instead, but that seems
     ;; unnecessarily obfuscated.
     (cons 'list accumulator))
    (t
     (error "Aargh. Unhandled"))))
```

Let's try it!

```
CL-USER> (diffs nil)
NIL
```

Not hugely exciting, but it looks plausible. Now use `macroexpand`, which just does the expansion without the evaluation:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(diffs nil))
(LIST)
T
```

And what if we'd already got some stuff from a recursion?

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(diffs nil ((- a b) (- b c))))
(LIST (- A B) (- B C))
T
```

Looks good! Now we need to deal with the case when there's an actual list there. The test you want is `consp` and (for my example) it only makes sense when there's at least two elements.

```
(defmacro diffs (lst &optional accumulator)
  (cond
    ;; A list of at least two elements
    ((and (consp lst) (consp (cdr lst)))
     (list 'diffs (cdr lst)
           (cons (list '- (cadr lst) (car lst)) accumulator)))
    ;; A list with at most one element
    ((listp lst)
     (cons 'list accumulator))
    (t
     (error "Aargh. Unhandled"))))
```

This seems almost to work:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(diffs (3 4 5)))

(LIST (- 5 4) (- 4 3))
T
```

but for two problems:

1. The list comes out backwards
2. The code is a bit horrible when we actually construct the recursive expansion

Let's fix the second part first by using the backtick operator:

```
(defmacro diffs (lst &optional accumulator)
  (cond
    ;; A list of at least two elements
    ((and (consp lst) (consp (cdr lst)))
     `(diffs ,(cdr lst)
             ,(cons `(- ,(cadr lst) ,(car lst)) accumulator)))
    ;; A list with at most one element
    ((listp lst)
     (cons 'list accumulator))
    (t
     (error "Aargh. Unhandled"))))
```

Hmm, it's not actually much shorter, but I think it's clearer.

For the second part, we *could* proceed by adding each item to the end of the accumulator rather than the front, but that's not particularly quick in Lisp because lists are singly linked. Better is to construct the accumulator backwards and then reverse it at the end:

```
(defmacro diffs (lst &optional accumulator)
  (cond
    ;; A list of at least two elements
    ((and (consp lst) (consp (cdr lst)))
     `(diffs ,(cdr lst)
             ,(cons `(- ,(cadr lst) ,(car lst)) accumulator)))
    ;; A list with at most one element
    ((listp lst)
     (cons 'list (reverse accumulator)))
    (t
     (error "Aargh. Unhandled"))))
```

Now we get:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(diffs (3 4 5)))

(LIST (- 4 3) (- 5 4))
T
```

Much better!

Two last things. Firstly, I still have an error clause in my macro. Can you see how to trigger it? Can you think of a better behaviour than just outputting an error? (Your macro is going to have to deal with the same problem)

Secondly, for debugging recursive macros like this, I recommend using `macroexpand-1` which just unfolds one level at once. For example:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(diffs (3 4 5)))
(DIFFS (4 5) ((- 4 3)))
T
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 *)
(DIFFS (5) ((- 5 4) (- 4 3)))
T
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 *)
(LIST (- 4 3) (- 5 4))
T
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your logic. First you are calling reverse on each iteration instead of at the end of the iteration. Then you are accumulating the new values, through `cons`, in the `cdr` of the cons cell as opposed to the `car`.

Also I don't see why this have to be a macro so using a function.

```
(defun matrix-add-row (r1 r2 sum-row)
  (if (or (endp r1) (endp r2))
      (reverse sum-row)
      (matrix-add-row (cdr r1)
                      (cdr r2)
                      (cons (+ (car r1) (car r2))
                            sum-row))))

(matrix-add-row '(1 2) '(3 4) ())
;; => (4 6)
```

Comment: I can make a regular function myself, but the homework is explicitly recursion macro.